# Trying to remove white space between nav bar and content?

Tags: css

If you go to my site - www.sorensenes.com - there is at least an inch of white space between nav bar and the main picture on the page. How can I get rid of that white space and move the picture up closer to the nav bar? I have been searching online for most of the afternoon trying different suggestions but nothing is working...help!?!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a CSS issue. Adding this to the bottom of your page will help.

```
<style>
  body main#primary {
      background: #fff;
      padding-top: 10px;
  }

  main#primary .wrapper {
      padding: 0px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
  }
</style>
```